# Little help on RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I have to parse a quite complex string to "evaluate" functions contained in the string. I have only one function to "extract" and it has this specific sintax:

```
LOC_POS(number;number);
```

This string is contained in an HTML page like this:

```
something here LOC_POS(45;9);Some string or html content <br> here LOC_POS(45.21312;9.1232123);LOC_POS(45,32;9,12); some other string...
```

(numbers are coordinates and the function is recognized by this RegEx:

```
LOC_POS\([ 0-9.,]+;[ 0-9.,]+\);
```

How can I extract all blocks in c#? The result I want to have is an array containing (one row per item)

```
something here 
LOC_POS(45;9);
Some string or html content <br> here 
LOC_POS(45.21312;9.1232123);
LOC_POS(45,32;9,12); 
some other string...
```

I know how to do it with normal string parsing..

Comment: it's the best task for more flexible and string-working oriented language Perl, so: split/pattern/, $yourstring.

Comment: can you use another language for this task?

Comment: @loldop Why? C# has regex, does it not?

Comment: @DavidB ok, answer for this question: it has a regex library and it doesn't oriented on this task: string-handling, searching and replacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what I came up with.

```
        string str = @"something here LOC_POS(45;9);Some string or html content <br> here LOC_POS(45.21312;9.1232123);LOC_POS(45,32;9,12);  some other string...";
        Regex test = new Regex(@"(LOC_POS\([\d\.,]+;[\d\.,]+\);)");
        string[] segments = test.Split(str);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string s in segments)
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                sb.AppendLine(s);
        textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

output results

```
something here 
LOC_POS(45;9);
Some string or html content <br> here 
LOC_POS(45.21312;9.1232123);
LOC_POS(45,32;9,12);
 some other string...
```

The regex finds each instance of the LOC_POS, the split causes it to break up the string into its segments, then you rebuild the string using a stringbuilder to get all the newLines in the right spot.  You can also use this to capture the individual instances of the LOC block if you actually need them.  The capture group around the whole thing is to make sure that the LOC blocks actually get located, rather than ignored.

Comment: it works perfectly. I changed the regex to match also another function, but it works!

Comment: you should "accept" the answer then, and Glad I could help =D

Answer (score 0):

`((.*?)(LOC_POS\([\d\.,]+;[\d\.,]+\);))`

That will capture several groups. The first sub-group will be a string before LOC_POS. [Regexr here.](http://regexr.com?314rl)

Group 1: full string

Group 2: string before LOC_POS

Group 3: LOC_POS call

Comment: if it has sequence of LOC_POS ? it regex capture too much.

Comment: Yeah, it will only grab what's followed by LOC_POS.

Comment: No, I expect 6 groups.. but I have only 3.. the full string (twice) and the string before loc_pos

Comment: @AndreaCi You're right, I forgot a capturing group. Group 1: full string, Group 2: string before LOC_POS, Group 3: LOC_POS call

Comment: @AndreaCi have you looked at my answer? I have tested it and it works as you requested in your question.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
string str = @"something here LOC_POS(45;9);Some string or html content <br> here LOC_POS(45.21312;9.1232123);LOC_POS(45,32;9,12);  some other string...";
string rgx = @"\s*(LOC_POS\([ 0-9.,]+;[ 0-9.,]+\);)\s*";

str = Regex.Replace(str, rgx, @"##$1##");
//Console.WriteLine("str= " + str);

string[] lines = str.Split(new string[] {"##"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach(string s in lines) {
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

First I put an arbitrary split-sequence (I used `##`, but you can change it to whatever) around the `LOC_POS` elements (using your regex with whitespace catching). Then I split the string on said split-sequence, making sure to handle empty entries. Boom, done.

Answer (score -1):

```
var content = "....";
var regex = new Regex(@"LOC_POS\([ 0-9.,]+;[ 0-9.,]+\);");
var matches = regex.Match(content);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and provides no explanation.

Comment: No, It gives only the first loc_pos as result